# How can I get glossaries to provide an index without a title

Tags: glossaries

I'm using a legacy LaTeX style which seems to be incompatible with `glossaries`:
when I ask for

```
\printnoidxglossary[type=index,style=mcolindex,sort=use]
```

I get the index I need, but its title is a *section title* even though this is a style with *chapters* as the highest hierarchical level and I need the index to have a chapter-like title. Is there some way I can ask `glossaries` to provide the index without the title, so that I can write

```
\chapter*{List of Notations}
\printnoidxglossarynotitle[type=index,style=mcolindex,sort=use]
```

and not get the title twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no experiences with Legacy styles, but is the code below working for your intentions? (`mcolindex` does not work for me here)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[acronym,toc,section=chapter]{glossaries}
\loadglsentries{example-glossaries-brief}

%\makeglossaries  % for \printglossary
\makenoidxglossaries  % for printnoidxglossary
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \glsaddall

    %\setglossarysection{chapter} % atm not necessary because of the chosen package option
    %\printglossary[title={List of Notations},style=treegroup]
    \printnoidxglossary[title={List of Notations},style=treegroup]

    \newpage
    \chapter*{List of Notations}
    %\printglossary[title={},style=treegroup]
    \printnoidxglossary[title={},style=treegroup]

    \newpage
    \setglossarysection{section} % set level on the fly
    %\printglossary[title={List of Notations},style=treegroup]
    \printnoidxglossary[title={List of Notations},style=treegroup]
\end{document}
```

Comment: In fact the option `section=chapter` did the trick, thank you!

Comment: There is still a problem: the headers produced by this chapter are in lowercase, how can I get them in uppercase?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? The glossary-title itself as chaptertitle? Or in the toc? (perhaps to be answered in a new question?)